# Smallest integer which cannot be derived from set of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Let's assume that I have `k` number of `n`s (e.g. `6,6` , k = 2 , n = 6)

I'd like to find the smallest integer larger than 1 which cannot be derived by any combination of these numbers

Here by combination I mean all the numbers which can be derived by putting 4 main operators (+ , - , / , *) between these numbers.

For example, the numbers which can be created by 2 6's are :

$6 + 6 = 12$

$6 \cdot 6 = 36$

$6 - 6 = 0 $

$\frac 66 = 1$

Therefore, the smallest such integer would be 2.

I solved this problem in brute force. Is there any better way ? because here the time and space complexity are very high.

```
public static int smallest_non_combined(int n , int k){
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    combination((double)n, k, set, 1 , (double)n);
    double r = 2;
    while (set.contains(r))
        r++;
    return (int)r;
}
public static void combination(double n , int k , HashSet<Integer> set , int index , double r){
    if (index >= k){
        if (r > 1 && r == (int)r)
            set.add((int)r);
    }else{
        combination(n , k , set , index+1, r + n);
        combination(n , k , set , index+1, r * n);
        combination(n , k , set , index+1, r / n);
        combination(n , k , set , index+1, r - n);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I echo Ross's question about parentheses and order of operations. Also, are intermediate fractions allowed?

Comment: The way I interpret your question is: "Given $k$ natural numbers $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k$ (not necessarily distinct), find the smallest natural number not equal to an expression constructed of parentheses, the basic arithmetic operators, and those numbers".  Is that correct?  Your example code doesn't seem to answer that question (for instance, where is the input corresponding to the $n_{i}$?)  Also, do you need to use all of the provided numbers, or just some?

Comment: Also, does a leading negative constitute as an operation? For example, do you want to count -6+6, -6-6, -6*6, and -6/6? These turn out all <0, but I imagine there are cases where it will give new solutions.

Comment: @sasha: That doesn't matter, since for multiplication and division a unary "-" applied to either operand just changes the overall sign, and a sign change on one operand interchanges addition and subtraction (both of which are allowed), possibly with an overall sign change.  So you can always pull all unary "-" operators up to the top of the parse tree.

Comment: Actually parenthesis is allowed but I thought that it wouldn't affect the set of possible values ! Negative sign is not allowed

Comment: Besides , we don't have distinct numbers ! as I said we have k number of n's , like three 6's , or ten 5's.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), you can get rid of the parenthesis all together. Then generating the combinations is fairly trivial:

for three 5s we have two possibilities, `+` denotes an operation which can be `+`, `-`, `/` or `*`:

```
5 5 5 + +      √
5 5 + 5 +      √
5 + + 5 5      X
+ 5 5 5 +      X
...
```

One observation is that the expression always starts with two numbers from left and always ends with an operators. You can start from left and two numbers and either add a number or an operator. At each step number of operators should not equal number of operands. For instance, if you get to the point that you have:

```
5 5 5 + + +
```

You can discard and generate next combination. But even with this approach calculating for 10 2s is quite time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  It is *much* worse if all the numbers are different.  You basically can create all the $4^{k-1}$ expressions and evaluate them, but even that will have trouble depending on the rules for parentheses.  For example, can I write $(5+5)*(5+5)=100$ under your rules?  If so it is even worse, as well.  If you always operate left to right (no parentheses) and have different numbers, you get $k!4^{k-1}$, which grows very rapidly as you say.

Comment: Yes we have to assume parenthesis too , but I guess the time complexity would be much worse than what you said , it would be `Catalan number for k elements` instead of `k!` , right ?

Comment: The Catalan numbers grow more slowly than the factorials, but the factorial goes away if all the numbers are the same.  An upper limit would be $C_k4^{k-1}$ but that is an overcount because it ignores that $+$ and $\times$ are commutative.

Comment: Now let's assume that I do this recursively by dividing the available number of elements to left and right sets and calculate each part and then combine them by use of 4 operators (actually to account for parenthesis), what would be time if I use memoization ? like to put the set of values for each number of elements in a map , how does it affect the running time ?

Comment: I don't have a simple answer, but that seems a good way to approach it.  Think of using a tree to represent the parentheses and giving a serial number and value to the smaller trees.  You can incorporate the commutativity by seeing each node as a factor 6, for four operators plus two directions for two of them.  It's not perfect as some values will still overlap, but should be pretty good.